# Text-Based RPG: Monster Compendium

Tags: python-3.x

all! I'm a fairly new programmer, and I've been using a text-based RPG as a sort of skill-building playground. Essentially I think of a new thing I want to add to the game that requires coding in a way I haven't done yet and work on implementing it until it works both in testing and in the regular game. I've been organizing it with VSCode and Git Hub, and it's fairly jumbled and needs a lot of work to organize it better, but [here is the link](https://github.com/Flintzer0/The-Castle/tree/main), for anyone who wants to take a look at it.

So, recently, I've been wanting to add a monster compendium.

```
def chk_compendium(self, enemy):
    if enemy.now_seen() == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def add_monster(self, enemy):
    if self.chk_compendium(enemy) == False:
        self.compendium.append(enemy)
        text_speed("You encountered a {} for your first time!\n".format(enemy.name), .03)
        time.sleep(.5)
        text_speed("You added the {} to your Monster Compendium!\n".format(enemy.name), .03)
        time.sleep(.5)
        enemy.see()

def view_compendium(self):
    if len(self.compendium) != 0:
        r = range(int(len(self.compendium)))
        for i in r:
            print(f'{i}: {self.compendium[i].name}')
        print(f'{len(self.compendium)}: Exit')
        monster = input("Which monster would you like to view? \n")
        if monster.isdigit():
            if int(monster) < len(self.compendium):
                print("\n" + self.compendium[int(monster)].__str__())
            elif int(monster) == len(self.compendium):
                pass
            else:
                print("Invalid choice.")
        elif monster == len(self.compendium):
            pass
        else:
            text_speed("Invalid choice.", .05)
    else:
        print("You haven't encountered any monsters yet!")
```

This code is located in the Player class. I thought I had everything good to go; it's set up so after combat is done, any new monster is immediately added to the compendium, which can then be viewed at the player's discretion. Or, so I thought. It works well enough, but it adds a new entry for every monster *instance*, which leads to duplicate entries (i.e. fight Giant Spider, get Giant Spider in compendium; fight another Giant Spider, get *another* Giant Spider in the compendium).

Here's how the Enemy Class is structured:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, mhp, damage, weak, DEF, RES, SPD, SKL, LUCK, EXP, gold, description):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.mhp = mhp
        self.damage = damage
        self.weak = weak
        self.DEF = DEF
        self.RES = RES
        self.SPD = SPD
        self.SKL = SKL
        self.LUCK = LUCK
        self.EXP = EXP
        self.gold = gold
        self.description = description
        self.seen = False
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n========================================\n{}========================================\nHP: {}\nDamage: {}\nWeakness: {}\nDEF: {}\nRES: {}\nSPD: {}\nSKL: {}\nLUCK: {}\n".format(self.name, self.description, self.mhp, self.damage, self.weak, self.DEF, self.RES, self.SPD, self.SKL, self.LUCK)
 
    def is_alive(self):
        return self.hp > 0
    
    def see(self):
        self.seen = True

    def now_seen(self):
        return self.seen
```

When the player enters a room with a monster, it has an object instance generated (that also stays dead after it's defeated), and from testing around with a few things it's the *object instance* saved in there, not the specific enemy class as a whole (i.e. `class giant_spider(Enemy)`), and I guess the way my function is built can't recognize them as of the same class, even with the `__repr__` function. How can I get the program to recognize them as being the same class (and thus not store each instance in the list)? Or, if anyone wants to share with me much better ways at how to program this (I am sure there are *several*), I'm open to that. Thanks!

Comment: handy a dead link!! What is the use if `The Castle.code-workspace`, and `__init__.py`? Since when did `print(end='')` stop working? You always print `see you next time`. How likely is it that you `import the_castle`. Maybe write a function that `types` some text on screen. `return player.inventory == items.Key`. Why is the world not a class (no need for globals), handle `\r\n` or `\n` IN your code, do not expect the users to modify the code. `return random.randint(1,100) <= ((player.SKL*2) + player.LUCK)` .........

Comment: if you just have 3 `{}` in the string why does `format` have 11 arguments? Why is there a redefinition of `save_and_exit(self)`? Aren't you afraid to fall a `sleep()`?

Comment: As I said, I'm a fairly new coder. What do you mean by a dead link, if you seem to be able to get to it just fine (based on the rest of your comment, anyways)? That code workspace should've been removed (I don't see it on my list in Git), Most of this is formatted as it is from me looking at guides for different things, and I still need to do a lot of cleanup to make it more uniform and stuff, I will work on that. I wasn't aware I had anything that was expecting the users to do anything other than type their inputs? Also, what do you mean when you just quote lines of code?

Comment: I tried to find guides that were more recent (within the last year or two), but it wasn't always easy for me to find for certain things. I'll do better about rechecking my code.

Comment: Wow; just realized that I had an old, incredibly out of date repository still up that was public, and the current one was set to private. Big L on my part, that's fixed.

Comment: Now the link works. just code means you can shorten lines of **your** code with that oneliner

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha. That makes sense. Didn't even register they were different from my own, haha; I will look at making those changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually figured out my own answer (though I really don't know how optimal it is):

I changed the `def chk_compendium(self, enemy)` to look like this:

```
def chk_compendium(self, enemy):
        if len(self.compendium) != 0:
            for m in self.compendium:
                if enemy.__class__ == m.__class__:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        else:
            return False
```

Tested that out a few times, and it works as I had wanted!

Comment: why do you loop if you only check the first element of `self.compendium`, what is the use of `if len(self.compendium) != 0:`, and you did not pick up any of the one liners I have shown you

Comment: The loop is to make sure it checks every entry in `self.compendium`; and the use of `if len(self.compendium) != 0:` is because without it, the game breaks when trying to add a monster to the compendium for the first time. Also, I definitely did add the one liners? I'll check again, though.

Comment: Okay, I had already added the `return random.randint(1,100) <= ((player.SKL*2) + player.LUCK)` for crits (moved it into the utilities.py file), as well as changed the `chk_SPD` function to read the same. I'm not actually sure where you were wanting me to change for the `return player.inventory == items.Key` one liner, though. I'll be going through all of the strings and .formats to fix any weird issues like you described.

Comment: Also, messing around with it, making World into a class seems to break the program entirely. I fixed all of the circular imports it generated, but it still has a bunch of new issues cropping up.

Comment: learn what `for` does with an iterable, and you ARE NOT checking every entry in `self.compendium`, the `if len()` is ueless

Comment: some one liners are from the old repo

Comment: Is not a for loop iterating it (i.e. the `m`) over `self.compendium` until there are no more entries to iterate over? I'll research it more. But I can't call it useless, because without it the code fails.

Comment: if the `useless` code is needed to have a bigger problem somewhere else in the code or in the whole design, use a debugger to see how the `for` loop works and read the doc about `for`